# Share Array between lua and C

Tags: c, lua, lua-table

I have really Googled this question but I never really got an solution.

I want to share an Array between C and Lua, for performance I will avoid copying Arrays to and from Lua.

So I want to pass a pointer to the Array from C to Lua. And then from Lua I want to set/modify values in this array directly.

---

**Example in C code**

I want to define my array

```
int mydata[] = {1,2,3,4}
```

set it global to access it from Lua with the name `mydata`.

---

**In Lua**

I want to change the values like this

```
mydata[3] = 9
```

and when I return to C, `mydata[3]` is 9 because it is a pointer to the array.

How is this possible?

Comment: Since lua is intended as an embeddable language to interface nicely with C, I would expect the lua documentation to provide ample examples. Did you browse this information already?

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer. I have looked almost any documentation, but I cant find examples with pointer to array.

Comment: It's Lua, not LUA. It's not an acronym; it's a name.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can expose arbitrary data to Lua via `userdata`. If you give your userdata values a *metatable*, you can define the behavior for various operators/operations on those userdata. In this case, we want to expose an array to Lua and define what to do in the case of `array[index]` and `array[index] = value`.

We expose the array to Lua by creating a userdata buffer large enough to hold the address of the array. We define the indexing/assignment behavior by created a metatable with the `__index` and `__newindex` methods.

Below is a complete, working example that exposes a static array to Lua. Your program will probably have some other call for returning the array to Lua. Note, there's no boundschecking at all; if you try to index outside the array bounds, you'll crash. To make this more robust, you'd want to change the userdata to a structure which has the array pointer and the array size, so you can do boundschecking.

```
#include "lauxlib.h"

// metatable method for handling "array[index]"
static int array_index (lua_State* L) { 
   int** parray = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "array");
   int index = luaL_checkint(L, 2);
   lua_pushnumber(L, (*parray)[index-1]);
   return 1; 
}

// metatable method for handle "array[index] = value"
static int array_newindex (lua_State* L) { 
   int** parray = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "array");
   int index = luaL_checkint(L, 2);
   int value = luaL_checkint(L, 3);
   (*parray)[index-1] = value;
   return 0; 
}

// create a metatable for our array type
static void create_array_type(lua_State* L) {
   static const struct luaL_reg array[] = {
      { "__index",  array_index  },
      { "__newindex",  array_newindex  },
      NULL, NULL
   };
   luaL_newmetatable(L, "array");
   luaL_openlib(L, NULL, array, 0);
}

// expose an array to lua, by storing it in a userdata with the array metatable
static int expose_array(lua_State* L, int array[]) {
   int** parray = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(int**));
   *parray = array;
   luaL_getmetatable(L, "array");
   lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
   return 1;
}

// test data
int mydata[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// test routine which exposes our test array to Lua 
static int getarray (lua_State* L) { 
   return expose_array( L, mydata ); 
}

int __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl luaopen_array (lua_State* L) {
   create_array_type(L);

   // make our test routine available to Lua
   lua_register(L, "array", getarray);
   return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
require 'array'

foo = array()
print(foo) -- userdata

-- initial values set in C
print(foo[1])
print(foo[2])
print(foo[3])
print(foo[4])

-- change some values
foo[1] = 2112
foo[2] = 5150
foo[4] = 777

-- see changes
print(foo[1])
print(foo[2])
print(foo[3])
print(foo[4])
```

Comment: Wow I can't thank you enough for this brilliant post with working examples. This is what I am looking for so thanks again!
I am new to this forum how can I give points to you?

Comment: for starters, like myself i really appreciated the ease of use of luabind - for your simply issue you see that a lot of code is required to do it directly in lua - with luabind, thats basically a one liner - you should check it out here is a great intro http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/luabind-introduction/ - after you get more comfortable with things, developing directly in lua is still better tho - however with luabind you can basically do alot of things very fast to get a working concept