# Sharing data between C and Lua version 5.2

Tags: lua

All,

See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689135/share-array-between-lua-and-c)

An excellent post on how to share data between C and Lua.  There is only one problem, it doesn't run on 5.2 due to missing luaL_openlib() support.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Jan

Comment: This is not really a new question but an update to the existing answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Lua 5.2, use `luaL_setfuncs(L,array,0)` instead of `luaL_openlib(L,NULL,array,0)`.

Comment: Thanks, will try and confirm result

Comment: @JanUlvesten, there may a couple of other details to fix when porting a 5.1 C library to 5.2, but nothing complicated.